# PHP MySQL inner join issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, inner-join

Basically I have two tables: nodes and nature. Nodes have an auto-incrementing ID, and nature has a 'node' column that is what I am focusing on here. The node column contains a delimited string of IDs from the nodes table (the nodes that the nature entry is in.)

An example of the node column in nature table might look like this:

```
.1.10.597.598.599.600.
```

There are periods in front and behind each id so I can search for all images in a node (WHERE node LIKE '%.".$_GET['id'].".%') for example.

That being said I am trying to select all entries from the node table that have entries in the nature table. Here's what I've got so far but it returns an empty set.

```
SELECT *
FROM nodes A
INNER JOIN nature B
ON A.id LIKE '%.B.node.%'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM nodes A
INNER JOIN nature B
ON B.node LIKE CONCAT('%.',A.id,'.%')
```

Note that this is quite expensive, as it prevents any use of index.

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13b39/3).

Comment: This doesn't quite work. Note that the when you are searching for %.B.node.% those periods are important because the node column is delimited by periods. So when I'm searching for node id of 597 it needs to be %.B.node.% since 597 is wrapped in periods. See example of node column I put in question. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed and added the periods. Sorry

Comment: Still interestingly it returns 409,248 results, where there are only 882 nodes and 464 nature entries. Aha, what it's doing is selecting all the nature entries for each nod entry (882* 464 = 409,248)

Comment: I missed something at first. It's the other way around. This seems to work.

Comment: still why is it returning 4,586 results... there are only 882 entries with nature entries in them.

Comment: aha i figured it out... it needs to be SELECT * 
FROM nodes A
INNER JOIN nature B ON B.node LIKE CONCAT(  '%.', A.id,  '.%' ) 
GROUP BY A.id b/c if there are multiple nature entries for a node it will re-select the node each time. Unfortunately group by is slow

Comment: Or you can try `DISTINCT` (maybe faster). But anyway, the most expensive part of the query is likely to remain the `LIKE` in the `JOIN` criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function

```
ON A.id LIKE CONCAT('%.',B.node,'.%')
```

Comment: Still returns an empty set. Also like I said in the other comment the periods are needed to wrap around the node id because they are delimiters.

Comment: I can update that, but you might also want to make sure the data exists, if it's returning an empty set.

Comment: The data exists. There are nodes with nature entries for mostly all of them.